# SharePoint 2013 stretched farm latency

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I'm planning to stretch our SP farm. I'm going to move 1 WFE and 1 APP to another data center.
Distance between data centers less than 10 km.

Based on this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-0) there are strong requirements:

> For a stretched farm architecture to work as a supported high-availability solution, the following prerequisites must be met:
>
> There is a highly consistent intra-farm latency of <1ms one way, 99.9% of the time over a period of ten minutes. (Intra-farm latency is commonly defined as the latency between the front-end web servers and the database servers.)
>
> The bandwidth speed must be at least 1 gigabit per second.

The question is - What if sometimes latency between remote WFE and DB server will be 3 or 4ms? Several times during 10 min period the latency was 3 ms.

What it will cause? Only low performance or something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this won't be an issue but you may run into support problems if you open a case with Microsoft if you cannot demonstrate that level of response time.

The general recommendation is to not stretch farms, instead implementing a DR farm (though 10KM is a very short distance where a major geological event or similar would likely impact both locations).

Comment: Thank You Trevor for response. We will implement DR infrastructure later, at this moment we want to build HA infrastructure.